# Looking for a shortcut for specificying parameters in an ObectDataSource UpdateMethod

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, objectdatasource

I am using an `ObectDataSorce` in my asp.net C# code, with `SelectMethod()` that calls a method that `returns List< Employee>`.

(I don't think it matters to the question, but I am displaying the data in the UI in an infragistics webdatagrid.)

I am working on `UpdateMethod()` now.

I tried using `Employee employee` as the input parameter to the method, as I used as the parameter in the `SelectMethod()`, but the compiler is looking for each property in Employee broken out as a separate parameter, i.e. `String Fn, String Ln, String Address1` , etc.

Any there any shortcuts for doing this rather than creating the method with a whole long list of parameters? Or leaving out the parameters for stuff that was readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set ObjectDataSource.DataObjectTypeName to Employee.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.dataobjecttypename.aspx